# Passing a protected 'card' array element from a sub class to a sub class

Tags: java, oop

I am able to find the card I want in passCard() but I been stumped on moving that card into the hand.

```
   public class CardContainer
{
    protected Card[] cards;
```

this is where i am trying to pass the card i find into the hand. i am able to find the card but been stuck after that.

```
public boolean passCard(CardContainer cc, Card c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
        {
            if(cards[i].equals(c)) 
            {       

                //this is where im trying to make magic happen


                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
}
}

public class Hand extends CardContainer {

    private String playerName;

    public Hand(String name, int numCards)
    {
        playerName = name;
        cards = new Card[numCards];

        // manually entered a card to test if it works
        cards[1] = new Card(1,'s');
    }
}



public class TestDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hand h = new Hand("name", 10);
    System.out.println(deck.passCard(h, new Card(2,'s')));

    // prints manually entered card in hand class
    h.printCards();
}
```

Comment: Can somebody please fix this terrible formatting

Comment: @faris working on it

Comment: Do you want this method to create a new `Hand` object or pass the `Card` to an existing `Hand`?

Comment: @GBlodgett I'm trying to pass Card to an existing Hand. I accidentally left that part out in main(). ...... Hand h = new Hand("name", 10);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `passCard` function you can simply initialize an element in `Cards` (This is assuming you want to initialize it at position `i`):

```
public boolean passCard(CardContainer cc, Card c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
    {
        if(cards[i].equals(c)) 
        {       
            h.cards[i] = this.cards[i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since `cards` is only `protected`:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package

Meaning that your `Hand` class can access it.